# Ajax/jQuery - How to display new elements and load a page into a container without completly reloading the whole page?

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, authentication

I am trying to process a user login without reloading the whole page.
What I want to achieve is:

1. On initial page visit a login panel is shown in the `<div id="frame"></div>`-container, which is the main display area on the website

When a user logs in successfully:

1. A container `<div id="info"></div>` should fade in into the header of the site, holding information like "Logged in as: username" and a "logout" button
2. The login form should fade out
3. New page 'overview.php' should be loaded into `<div id="frame"></div>`, in place of the previously displayed login form

Currently when the login via `$.ajax()` is successful, 'overview.php' is being loaded into the`id="frame"` container, but only static `<html>` elements are displayed, not the ones that are being processed with **PHP** (ie. `echo "Test";`). However, if i press F5 to reload the whole website, all elements are being shown properly.

I assume that is due to **PHP** being processed server-sided. What is the correct way to achieve what I am trying to do?

**index.php**:

```
<div id="frame" class="center">
    <?php
        if(!isset($_SESSION['user']))
            include('./php/welcome.php');
        else
            include('./php/overview.php');
    ?>
</div>
```

**welcome.php**:

```
<div id="welcome">
    <form id="login" class="center" action="./php/auth.php" method="post">
        <div>Please login.</div>
        <input id="user" class="field" type="text" name="user" value="User" /></br>
        <input id="pass" class="field" type="password" name="pass" value="Pass" /></br>
        <input class="button" type="submit" name="submit" value="Anmelden" />
    </form>
    <div id="login_error" class="error_message center">
        error message
    </div>
</div>
```

**overview.php**:

```
<div id="overview" style="background: red">
    <?php
        if(!isset($_SESSION['user']))
            echo '<div class="error_message">error message</div>';
        else
            echo 'Why is this line only displayed after page refresh (F5)?';
    ?>
    Test, this is being displayed when overview.php is loaded via ajax
</div>
```

**index.js**:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //$('#frame').load('./php/welcome.php');
    $("#login").submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#login_error:visible').hide();
        $.ajax({
            url: './php/auth.php',
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(result) {
                        if(result.success == '1') {
                            $('#welcome').fadeOut(600);
                            $('#frame').load('./php/overview.php');
                        } else {
                            $('#login_error').fadeIn(600).delay(3500).fadeOut(600);
                        }   
                    }
        }); 
    });
    $("#logout").click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: './php/logout.php',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(result) {
                        if(result.logout == '1') {
                            $('.info, #overview').fadeOut(600);
                        } else {
                            alert('nope');
                        }
                    }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Are you watching the browser's console during the request / response to make sure that the data you're expecting to send / receive it going back and forth? Are there any errors?

Comment: I am fairly new to ajax and web development, I only had to deal with it a few times so far. How would I test if the data is being sent back and forth? At least there are no visible errors, the $_SESSION variable is set. The pages are loaded, just the PHP commands in **overview.php** are not processed unless I press F5.

Comment: Open up your browser's console window and then make the request. You'll see a lot of information. If there are any problems you'll see them there.

Comment: No errors, just warnings that the input fields for username and password are run in an insecure environment (http:// not https://). Both the POST header for auth.php and GET header for overview.php return OK.

Comment: auth.php returns JSON as you would expect? Does overview.php have a session_start() in it?

Comment: The JSON is returned as expected, I debugged that via `alert()`. The missing `session_start()` in **overview.php** was the problem! I assumed that it would use the `session_start()` call of **index.php** as it is being loaded into that one. I just added `session_start()` to **overview.php** and now the **PHP** is being processed correctly, aswell. Thank you very much good sir!

Comment: Any time you need to use session information in a page you must include session_start() at the top of the page. I have been bitten by this more than once :) Remember that the PHP is processed server-side before being loaded, so the current session_start() is of no consequence to those PHP files that might be loaded later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was a missing `session_start()` call in **overview.php**. Adding the call to the top of that file solved the issue.

Solution provided by Jay Blanchard, for more information read the comments.